# =SUMPRODUCT ( - - MIN ( INDEX (C:D) )) = A:B ) - Keep Calculation in the Same Cell - Returns 0

Tags: arrays, excel, sum, offset, sumproduct

[Picture of excel formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/twgSV.png)

I am hoping to sum an array of values from a calculation, however keeping all the formula in the one cell.

```
=--(MIN(INDEX(C2:C37,ROW(C2:C37)-ROWS(C2)),S2)-MAX(INDEX(B2:B37,ROW(B2:B37)-ROWS(B2)),R2)=C2:C37-B2:B37)
```

How do I sum or sumproduct the formula above to return a sum of the array? I would like to add something like this:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(MIN(INDEX(C2:C37,ROW(C2:C37)-ROWS(C2)),S2)-MAX(INDEX(B2:B37,ROW(B2:B37)-ROWS(B2)),R2)=C2:C37-B2:B37)**)**
```

The answer should be a 1, however it returns 0

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please set a tag of a programming language (seems to be Excel?). Otherways your question is hard to find.

Comment: What you are try to achieve. Please explain in brief.